# What are the typical instance parameters of non-commutative cryptographic schemes?

Tags: group-theory, domain-parameters, non-commutative-cryptography

Recently, I grew a tremendous interest for public-key cryptography based on "groupoids", and collaborated with someone on this topic. What I notice afterwards, is that there had been a huge body of work on "non-commutative" cryptography, with a book from 2011 dedicated to that topic titled "Non-commutative Cryptography and Complexity of Group-theoretic Problems" written by A.Myasnikov et al. (published by American Mathematical Society), although I haven't gotten access to its content yet.

Obviously, non-commutative cryptography had not been matured to the stage where they'd get hash-sign-numbered standards like PKCS#1 for RSA, SEC#1 for elliptic-curve, and EESS#1 for NTRU.

What this question asks is, what are the typical parameters proposed for non-commutative cryptographic schemes? What're their typical cryptogram sizes?

Comment: I think "non-commutative cryptographic scheme" is overly broad, as naturally the product in (M)LWE comes from $\mathsf{GL}_n(R)$, which is non-commutative in the case of module rank $n > 1$. I am assuming that this question is not interested in the parameters of (M)LWE though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common proposals around non-commutative cryptography have been around [braid groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group). Its proponents have struggled to find parameter sets that are agreed to resist security analysis. Recent proposals have included the [algebraic eraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Eraser) key establishment system and WalnutDSA, a signature scheme that was entered in the NIST post-quantum crytpography process, but [failed to pass the first round](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/round-1/official-comments/WalnutDSA-official-comment.pdf).

I don't know if there are currently any proposed parameters for the Algebraic Eraser scheme, but this [2016 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03870) gives a cryptanalysis of the scheme proposed for ISO/IEC 29167-20 standardisation (the standard was not published). The Algebraic Eraser authors' [response](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04780) is also available.

The [WalnutDSA submission](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/round-1/submissions/WalnutDSA.zip) can be found on the [website of the NIST process](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/Round-1-Submissions) (the WalnutDSA website link no longer works), as can the [cryptanalysis](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/round-1/official-comments/WalnutDSA-official-comment.pdf) that led to its non-progression.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would read Rusian: a Diffie-Hellman -like common key from non-commutative group operation.
http://mi.mathnet.ru/dan5041
http://www.mathnet.ru/rus/person17348